# After paytm payment gets success, I am not able to go back to my angular application

Tags: node.js, angular, express, payment-gateway, paytm

I am integrating Paytm payment gateway using angular 8, nodejs and expressjs. I am handling callback url event on server side(nodejs and expressjs) but I am not able to go back to my angular application after getting success callback url from the Paytm payment gatway. Please help me get this issue resolved.

My callback code(in expressjs):

```
app.post('/callback', (req,res) => {
        responsePayment(req.body).then(
            success => {
                res.render("response.ejs", {resultData: "true", responseData: success});
                console.log(res);
            },
            error => {
                res.send(error);
            }
        );
    })
}

const responsePayment = function(paymentObject) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      if (
        checksum_lib.verifychecksum(
          paymentObject,
          "my Merchant Key",
          paymentObject.CHECKSUMHASH
        )
      ) {
        resolve(paymentObject);
      } else {
        return reject('Error while verifying checksum');
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that checksum is not getting verified from the callback response.

Please use the latest checksum library given for nodejs on paytm developer page. The github link for the same is given here for your reference: https://github.com/paytm/Paytm_Node_Checksum
Refer to the method given here for validating checksum:

```
/* import checksum generation utility */
var PaytmChecksum = require("./PaytmChecksum");

paytmChecksum = request.body.CHECKSUMHASH;
delete request.body.CHECKSUMHASH;

var isVerifySignature = PaytmChecksum.verifySignature(request.body, config.PAYTM_MERCHANT_KEY, paytmChecksum);
if (isVerifySignature) {
    console.log("Checksum Matched");
} else {
    console.log("Checksum Mismatched");
}
```